# Why Qt Quick Application couldn't dynamically create a control by the Method Qt.createComponent

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

In my Qt Quick Application, I wanna use Qt.createComponent to create component dynamically——the effect I expect: when I click the button"create checkbox" ,the window will create a CheckBox dymamically

I made it in a Qt Quick UI prototype(qml-only project),but failed in the Qt Quick Application

After running the app, I click the button"create checkbox" many times, but the window has no response and the program stuck

[image]

```
// app.pro
QT += quick

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target



//main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine> 
#include <QQmlComponent>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}

// CheckBox.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
CheckBox{
    text: "checkcheck"

}

//main.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id:root
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button{
        text: "create checkbox"
        anchors.centerIn:parent
        onClicked: loadCheckBox(root)
    }

    function loadCheckBox(parent){
        var obj=Qt.createComponent("CheckBox.qml");
        if(obj.status==Component.Ready){
            var checkBox=obj.createObject(parent)
        }

    }
}
```

My environment: Win10  QtCreator  Qt5.13.2_MSVC2017_64bit

Anyone knows how to modify it?

Comment: Just rename `CheckBox.qml` to `MyCheckBox.qml` or similar. You should avoid naming custom components the same way as existing ones.

Comment: Printing the error string should help: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#errorString-method

Comment: @folibis  thanks you so much!!!!  I solved the problem!!!!   : )